# Laravel Mail Send Attach Wrong Encoding

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Im sending a csv attachement file, but laravel send the csv with wrong encoding when someone opens the email.

In my case since is in portuguese language the csv file have special charecters like ã, ç, ão. €,..

Example code:
```

```
class MailCron extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $csv;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($csv)
    {
        $this->csv = $csv;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->from('info@domain.com')
            ->view('mail.leads')
            ->attach($this->csv->store("csv",false,true)['full']);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding the CSV to UTF8.

Comment: in the csv file is ok, the issue that i found was when i send the email threw  laravel. I tried to send the csv by other email provider (gmail..) and when i open the email it doesnt show the strange charecters. So the only problem is the the laravel side. How can i enforce the header encoding on the Mailable?

Answer (score 0):

This should set the headers in the mail:

```
public function build()
{
    $this->withSwiftMessage(function (\Swift_Message $message) {
        $message->getHeaders()
            ->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    });

    return $this->from('info@domain.com')
        ->view('mail.leads')
        ->attach($this->csv->store("csv",false,true)['full']);
}
```

Be sure to check with header **text/plain** and **text/html**.